# How to add values in cells under an actual table

Tags: excel, vba, datatable, return-value, offset

I need to add value in cells under different tables sizes, i think using offset under the table is a way to do it

This is my try:

Making a table as a object:

```
Sub LisObjectsTable()

Dim LR As Long
Dim LC As Long

 
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LC = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Dim Rng As Range

Set Rng = Cells(1, 1).Resize(LR, LC)

Dim Ws As Worksheet
Set Ws = ActiveSheet

Ws.ListObjects.Add xlSrcRange, xllistobjecthasheaders:=xlYes, Destination:=Rng

Ws.ListObjects(1).Name = "ActTable"

End Sub
```

And then this:

```
    Sub AddValues()

Dim MyTable As ListObject
 
Set MyTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("ActTable")

With ListObjects("ActTable")
    .Offset(1, 0).Value = "Costo de envío"
    .Offset(2, 0).Value = "Número de unidades"
 End With

End Sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you're asking about adding rows to existing tables then you can use the `ListRows.Add` method - that returns the just-added `ListRow` object and you can populate that using its `Range` property.

Comment: Could you share where you are supposed to write these two strings (row and column of the table)?

Comment: Under a current table, it can short like (A1:F20) or (A1:F100). So i'm trying to add values (specific text) under such table for example there is the table and after 3 cells below of it i want write the values.

Answer (score 1):

### Write to Cells Below an Excel Table

- *Below*, instead of *under*, is the more accurate word.

```vb
Sub AddValues()

    Const TableName As String = "ActTable"
    Const EmptyRowsCount As Long = 3
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim dCell As Range
    
    With ws.ListObjects(TableName).Range
        Set dCell = .Resize(1, 1).Offset(.Rows.Count + EmptyRowsCount)
    End With
    
    dCell.Value = "Costo de envío"
    dCell.Offset(1).Value = "Número de unidades"

End Sub
```